# Get Windows command to run through system/shell.exec

Tags: r, windows

I use the [Windows command `tree`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true) often to print out a tree diagram of the contents of files.  I'd like to add this to my workflow in R but can't get the command to run though `system` or `shell.exec` and can't figure out why.  Here is a reproducible example with 4 approaches and error messages using `shQuote` (with and without) in `system` and `shell.exec` command.  When I use `cat` I can paste the command to the Windows command line manual (not using R) and the tree diagram is produced.  What am I doing incorrectly that I can't make this run in R?

```
## build some mock files and directories with lapply
lapply(file.path("TEMP", c("", "X", "Y")), dir.create)
lapply(file.path("TEMP", paste0(c("A", "B"), ".txt")), file.create)

## create path to external file
out <- file.path(getwd(), "TREE.txt")

## create the tree command
cmd <- paste("tree", shQuote(file.path(getwd(), "TEMP")), "/f /a >", shQuote(out))
cat(cmd)  ## view it

system(cmd)  ## attempt 1

cmd <- paste("tree", shQuote(file.path(getwd(), "TEMP")), "/f /a >", shQuote(out))
shell.exec(cmd)  ## attempt 2

cmd2 <- paste("tree", file.path(getwd(), "TEMP"), "/f /a >", out)
system(cmd2)  ## attempt 3
shell.exec(cmd2)  ## attempt 4

cat(cmd, file="clipboard")


## > out <- file.path(getwd(), "TREE.txt")
## > cmd <- paste("tree", shQuote(file.path(getwd(), "TEMP")), "/f /a >", shQuote(out))
## > cat(cmd)
## tree "C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TEMP" /f /a > "C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TREE.txt"> 
## > system(cmd)
## Too many parameters - >
## > 
## > cmd <- paste("tree", shQuote(file.path(getwd(), "TEMP")), "/f /a >", shQuote(out))
## > shell.exec(cmd)
## Error in shell.exec(cmd) : 
##   'tree "C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TEMP" /f /a > "C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TREE.txt"' not found
## > 
## > 
## > cmd2 <- paste("tree", file.path(getwd(), "TEMP"), "/f /a >", out)
## > system(cmd2)
## Too many parameters - >
## > shell.exec(cmd2)
## Error in shell.exec(cmd2) : 
##   'tree C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TEMP /f /a > C:/Users/trinker/Desktop/TREE.txt' not found
```

Comment: Probably not the best programming wise but if it works yes.  I am hoping for a way to send the full paths directly but if that's not possible switching the wd may be the best approach.

Comment: @Thomas good call that works.

Comment: @user20650 can you put the `shell` as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `shell`. On Windows, `system` does not use a shell (it only runs system commands). You're trying use a pipe to redirect output, thus you encounter the problem noted in `? system`:

> `command` must be an executable (extensions ‘.exe’, ‘.com’) or a batch file (extensions ‘.cmd’ and ‘.bat’): these extensions are tried in turn if none is supplied.) This means that redirection, pipes, DOS internal commands, ... cannot be used: see `shell` if you want to pass a shell command-line.